# Can't compile android apps

Tags: android, xamarin, emulation

I want to start developing apps for android using Xamarin, but there is one problem - Emulator. I have downloaded Xamarin android emulator, but it seems that my video card is not as good, and it takes a lot of time to start an emulator and to start an application on him. I have also tried connecting my phone to a computer and using USB debugging, but it seems that Visual Studio can not recognize it and I have no option of compiling an app. I have HTC Desire 310, also tried using some additional software to help compile on my phone but it is just not working. Can anyone help me, how I can compile applications on my phone, or recommend me an emulator that is suitable for a lower computers. Thanks.

Comment: You should probably try to solve the USB connection issue first.  Solutions will depend on your phone and host operating system, but there are many existing questions and answers on numerous varieties of both here.

Comment: That link applies to the Google Emulator, but is sounds like he is using the Xamarin Android Player

Comment: Yes I am using Xamarin Android Player. As for the USB connection issue, it connects just fine and I can put pictures,music, etc.. on my phone, the problem is that Visual Studio can't recognize that the phone is connected, and it doesn't give me an option to compile on my phone. When I go to device manager it tells me like im missing some driver for Android USB connection, I don't understand what I need to download, I've tried downloading various drivers for HTC and for Android USB connection but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: @Ognjen This is because you're missing the neccessary drivers. These are a real b*tch to for HTC. Caused me quite some problems aswell, not to mention the time spent on finding something that'd helped me. I can't find the tool I used before, but I think this should work: [Adb driver website](http://adbdriver.com/downloads/).

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled Developer Options on your phone?  Assuming your phone has >= 4.0 you can follow this guide to enable developer options:

[Enable Developer Settings Android 4.0](http://www.androidcentral.com/how-enable-developer-settings-android-42)

Now with dev options enabled:

On your phone goto Settings -> Developer Options Enable USB Debugging

Now if Visual Studio still can't see your phone it's possible you have two instances of the Android SDK installed and the ADB are fighting eachother or Visual Studio is looking in the wrong directory.

Open Visual Studio -> Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Android Settings -> Android SDK Location

Make sure you're pointing to the correct SDK Location on disk.

Now try the command line and see if ADB can see your device, open command line and navigate to SDK location root/platform-tools and run the command

adb devices

if your phone still does not show up it's possible you've installed the wrong USB drivers for your phone.  you can also try

adb kill-server
adb start-server 
adb devices

to double check if ADB sees your device.